# How to use a lambda function with std::replace_if()?

Tags: c++, lambda, replace

I am trying to write a function that will replace a Song in a set if there IDs match.

I am still a bit confused by lambda expressions.

I am trying to use replace_if but I am not sure how to reference the original song in the expression.

m_songs is a set of song objects

I want to replace with whichever song in m_song shares the ID with newSong.

So basically how do I get the ids from m_songs in the replace if statement?

```
std::replace_if(m_songs.begin(), m_songs.end(),
     newSong.getID() == (One of the m_songs?)getID() , newSong) ;
```

Comment: @user0042 yes I am struggling to understand lambada functions.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda

Comment: You don't have enough code here to tell, but I don't think you need a lambda here, just an old-value.

Comment: What is the declaration for `m_songs`?   Is it `set<Song>`  or `vector<Song>`, or something else?

Comment: @msandiford it is a set

Comment: @MichaelGrinnell I’m pretty sure this sort of modification isn’t legal on sets, because they’re stored in order so anything that could change the order can break things.

Comment: With a set you must use the set member functions `erase` and `insert` to replace an element. You cannot just rewrite it.

Comment: @ZanLynx And I think that doesn’t work while iterating, either. You can erase the current element while iterating if you do it carefully, but inserting while iterating just won’t work well, I think. Although it might be possible to get it to work depending on the comparison function you use.

Comment: @DanielH: Insertion into a set doesn't invalidate iterators. You do need to be prepared for the possibility that your iteration will run over your inserted element, if it got inserted after your iterator position.

Comment: @ZanLynx Right, which is harder to handle than with `erase`, where you can just set your loop iterator to the returned result and be sure of not missing anything.

Comment: @DanielH: Sets are not vectors. In this case they're more like linked lists.

Comment: @ZanLynx I am aware. If sets were like vectors, there would be complications with inserting *before* the point as well. But it’s still easier to handle the complications involved with erasing mid-loop than with inserting mid-loop, and there are still complications because you need to make sure you don’t invalidate the current loop iterator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Song newSong = ...;
std::replace_if(std::begin(m_songs), std::end(m_songs), [&newSong](const &Song song) {
    return newSong.getID() == song.getID();
}, newSong);
```

You can also just capture the ID using this syntax (assuming id is a string):

```
[std::string id = std::move(newSong.getID()](const &Song song) { return id == song.getID(); }
```

The lambda function captures `newSong` by reference and is able to use it within the lambda, now all you need to do is check the id against each song that the lambda is called with.

The `replace_if` method calls the lambda function with each song in the collection of songs, so you don't need to iterate over all the songs in the method again

Comment: Wouldn’t it be better to directly capture `newSong.getID()`? Probably not much of an issue unless `getID` is more expensive than it looks, I suppose.

Comment: Ok I get that, i think it should be (Song const & song) tho.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a C++17 replace_if with lambda example for you.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<int> v{1,2,3,4,8,100};
    int match = 4;
    replace_if(v.begin(), v.end(), [&](auto x){return x == match;}, 9999);
    for(auto x: v) {
        cout << x << ' ';
    }
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I compiled it with

```
g++ -Wall -W -pedantic -g -std=c++17    replace-if-test.cpp   -o replace-if-test
```